# Remove all elements with <noscript> tag in html using UIWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview, noscript

I am trying to parse a html file in my Swift app and I wish to remove all elements with noscript tag. I've tried this but it didn't work

```
//webView is a UIWebView with html loaded
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("var noscript = document.getElementsByTagName('noscript');var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('div');for (var j in parent) {for(var i in noscript) {parent.removeChild(noscript[i]);}}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try a js code more like

```
var noscript = document.getElementsByTagName('noscript');
var index = noscript.length;
while(index--) {
    noscript[index].parentNode.removeChild(noscript[index]);
}
```

If we look at your js code, there is three things we can say

```
var noscript = document.getElementsByTagName('noscript');
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var j in parent) {
    // 1 - you iterate on parent but don't use the j variable
    for(var i in noscript) {
        // 2 - parent is an htmlcollection, not an htmlNode, it has no removeChild method
        // 3 - i will take for values 0...n but also 'item' and 'length'
        parent.removeChild(noscript[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Jerome's help, but I end up doing it with a pure Swift solution since I am not familiar with JavaScript. In case anyone need it, here's the function to remove all noscript elements :

```
func removeNoScript(var html : String) -> String {

    while html.rangeOfString("<noscript>") != nil {
        let startLocation = html.rangeOfString("<noscript>")?.startIndex
        let endLocation = html.rangeOfString("</noscript>")?.endIndex

        html.removeRange(startLocation! ..< endLocation!)
    }
    return html

}
```